# Google Colab script throws "Transport endpoint is not connected"

Tags: bash, python-2.7, google-colaboratory

I cannot use any bash commands in `Google Colab` script, it throws me: `Transport endpoint is not connected.` The problem only occurs in the mounted gdrive (I am using `google-drive-ocamlfuse`)

For instance, if I type:

```
>> cd drive/cnn/
[Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: 'drive/cnn/'
>> ls
ls: cannot access '.': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I have tried restarting the runtime but no luck.

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: From list of menus on Colab notebook, click 'Runtime' and select 'Restart Runtime'. This worked for me!

Comment: Noticed most ans. didn't explain the cause? Does this happen more often for large files or dir with many large files. It seems to be related to google drive and how it quota I/O.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Silly me, I just simply had to unmount and mount the drive again:

```
!fusermount -u drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Answer (score 18):

Goto Runtime on menubar and click on restart runtime option.

Or simply use the shortcut press CTRL + M

Answer (score 11):

What i did is run this code>

```
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount=True)
```

Then I saw my directory because I had to change the path

and it works to me!!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively: Terminate the session by going to : Runtime -> Manage Sessions, then Click on terminate for the session. Then you can re-mount the drive. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

try factory reset runtime hope it work

Comment: Hi Sharaiz, can you add some more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using Pro+ with background execution on.

Drive got refreshed after

```
1. Disconnect and delete runtime
2. mount
```