# How can I export a dataframe in Google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a dataset that I created from filtering another dataset. I used the following code to do the necessary changes:

```
new_df = df.groupby("IBGE").agg(Start=("DATE","min"),
                                End=("DATE","max"),
                                Mean_QTD=("QTD","mean"))
```

It works just fine, here are the types of variables in the new dataframe:

```
new_df.dtypes
```

```
Start: datetime64[ns]
End: datetime64[ns]
Mean_QTD: float 64
dtype: object
```

I then try to save this new dataframe on colab's files by doing the following and get the following error:

```
#I have tried both ('test.csv' and r'test.csv')
new_df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-f3a451cc52ad> in <module>()
----> 1 new_df.to_csv('test.csv')

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    705                 encoding=ioargs.encoding,
    706                 errors=errors,
--> 707                 newline="",
    708             )
    709         else:

OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: 'test.csv'
```

How can I get a turnaround from this error? I already have google colab authentications in place earlier on my notebook and I have no problem uploading files from my computer and Drive to the workplace, the only issue is saving this new dataset to Drive and eventually to my computer as a csv file.

Comment: Can you try the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588113/google-colab-script-throws-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected)?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588113/google-colab-script-throws-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected solve your problem?